# Unexpected output Dbdelta WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have looked at many other questions on here relating to this issue but none so far have been able to resolve mine.

As per the codex on dbDelta. SQL statements must:

> You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
>
> You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the
>   definition of your primary key.
>
> You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you
>   must include at least one KEY.
>
> You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
>
> Field types must be all lowercase.
>   SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) NOT NUL' at line 1]
```

But to my eyes my SQL statement conforms to dbDelta's requirements. **NB** the variables $table_name and $charset_collate  are defined earlier in the function.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      statistics longblob NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name. " (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      statistics longblob NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) " . $charset_collate . ";";
```